# Landscape orientation image picker.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm creating an app that is landscape only, it uses an image picker control.

Looking through the site I've discovered that apple only allow portrait for this for some reason. I'm okay with it flipping to portrait for this one section, if it means the user can select a photo from the library.
Below is my code that gives an error about it being in landscape mode. How do I fix this to say it's okay to flip it to portrait. thanks

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto{
takePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
takePicker.delegate = self;
[takePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:takePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
-(IBAction)chooseExisiting{
choosePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
choosePicker.delegate = self;
[choosePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:choosePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use ImagePickerController in portrait mode.
Just subclass it to open in landscape mode :

```
@interface NonRotatingUIImagePickerController : UIImagePickerController
@end

@implementation NonRotatingUIImagePickerController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
@end
```

After that, you can use your code with that class.

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto {
takePicker = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc]init];
takePicker.delegate = self;
[takePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:takePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

-(IBAction)chooseExisiting{
choosePicker = [[NonRotatingUIImagePickerController alloc]init];
choosePicker.delegate = self;
[choosePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:choosePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work for me in Swift 3.

Even if I also override supportedInterfaceOrientations, I get this exception: 
    'UIApplicationInvalidInterfaceOrientation', reason: 'Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [PUUIAlbumListViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

Comment: Sorry folks, all solutions do not work for me. When I allow UIImagePickerController to be portrait and do export the video choosen, it gets rotated in some strange ways. Has anybody got any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why present an error at all? Why not just present the image picker in portrait? People are smart enough to rotate their device. Or you could write your own landscape image picker, or use one of the several open source ones available.

Comment: that's what im going to do now. So I need to select portrait when i deselected it. Do I need to put code into each individual view controller telling it to stay in landscape?

Comment: I just select portrait and landscape at the start, then every view controller that I wanted only to appear in landscape I entered the code below.

        - (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
        }
        - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
        }